# Windows 8 redraw/repaint issues

Tags: windows-8, drivers

This is what happens when I scroll a window (click for full-size versions):

[image]

[image]

It can happen in any application, even in Chrome.

My computer's specs:

- ASUS p8z77-v motherboard
- Intel Core-i7 3770k
- Intel HD Graphics 4000 integrated VGA
- Windows 8 Pro x64

I have tried to reinstall VGA drivers, tried to install an older driver from intel.com or asus.com, but no success with resolving the issue. Currently I am using driver version 2867.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

First things first, these can be  aresult of lot of things. First this can be an issue with Cache date from internet. Use CCleaner to check if the cache data can be wiped off.

Check The Direct X version.

On the main screen of Windows 8 type `run`. The run window will open in Desktop. Check for Direct X version and every component in `dxdiag` to see if it is causing an issue and if required update it.

The screenshots are given below.

[image]
[image]

[image]

Also update the [DirectX End-User Runtime Web Installer](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35)

Comment: i will try to find another....

Comment: I'll try inserting another VGA and let you know about results.

Comment: **UPDATE**: everything works fine with another VGA card (nvidia). So the problem definitely related to Intel HD graphics 4000 drivers.

Comment: **UPDATE2**: Intel released new drivers 2875. Problem still exists.

Comment: @obuolys You responded earlier that the issue got resolved is it still the same?